# range of binned_statistic in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

Hi I am trying to bin some data in frequency bins using the following:

```
import scipy as sc
sc.stats.binned_statistic([0, 1, 0, 0 ,1], py.arange(1), 
                          statistic="count", bins=2, range=(0, 2.0) )
```

This produces an error (below) which does not occur without the `range` argument. The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html#scipy.stats.binned_statistic) for this function suggest `range=(float, float)` should do the trick.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-1cf57b135132> in <module>()
  1 
 ----> 2 sc.stats.binned_statistic([0, 1, 0, 0 ,1], py.arange(1), statistic="count",    bins=2, range=(0,2))

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_binned_statistic.pyc in binned_statistic(x, values, statistic, bins, range)
      90 
      91     medians, edges, xy = binned_statistic_dd([x], values, statistic,
 ---> 92                                              bins, range)
      93 
      94     return medians, edges[0], xy

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_binned_statistic.pyc in binned_statistic_dd(sample, values, statistic, bins, range)
    281         smax = np.zeros(D)
    282         for i in np.arange(D):
--> 283             smin[i], smax[i] = range[i]
    284 
    285     # Make sure the bins have a finite width.

    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `arange(2)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is with the second argument, not with the `range` keyword argument. The second argument must be "the same shape as `x`" according to the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html). Try this:

```
sc.stats.binned_statistic([0, 1, 0, 0, 1], np.arange(5), 
                          statistic="count", bins=2, range=(0, 2.0))
```

**EDIT** As @DSM pointed out, my correction was for another error not yet showing up, so this doesn't work as is. `binned_statistic` makes a call to [`binned_statistic_dd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd.html), which expects "A sequence of lower and upper bin edges," one per dimension. Looks like a bug on SciPy you can work around by doing:

```
sc.stats.binned_statistic([0, 1, 0, 0, 1], np.arange(5), 
                          statistic="count", bins=2, range=[(0, 2.0)])
```

Comment: That still errors out for me.  Regardless of what the docs seem to say, it looks to me like the code expects `range` (if not `None`) to be an iterable of pairs, not a pair itself.

Comment: Yep, you are right: it makes a call to `binned_statistic_dd`, which expects an iterable of pairs, one per dimension. Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: Thanks for that Jaime, I felt I was going crazy over this one!